# Visual Studio Enterprise Git Merge completed with conflicts

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

This approach used to work before - I'm not sure what is different. I'm working on a sub branch and have a bunch of my changes and there have been changes to the main branch made by others. I want to get those changes on my sub branch.

In Git Changes I go to remotes and select the mainBranch then "merge into current branch" as below
[image]

I get prompted with:

[image]

Finally I get the error:
[image]

Comment: The reason of the conflicts is related to the changes made on each branch, and not to the topology of them. Here https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts a good explanation of conflicts and resolution techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was that I needed to commit my changes first. After that I could proceed as per above.